# Modifying search function to exclude posts and limit results to 10 per page on front end only

Tags: php, wordpress

This problem is kind of two part. I have the solution to exclude posts from the search and limit the results to 10 results per page but the problem is it also affects the backend wp-admin area. So if i search for posts through the wp-admin area the posts will be excluded even though I only want this to occur for users who are not admin. This is the code I have for excluding posts and limiting the results to 10:

```
function SearchFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'page');
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');

function change_wp_search_size($query) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) // Make sure it is a search page
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 10;

    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'change_wp_search_size');
```

Now I have done a little bit of reading and research on stack and other sites and it looks like there is a way to only trigger these functions only after checking if admin is logged in. I'll reference to the [wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) for the is_admin function

This is the way I attempted to use the is_admin function which caused an http error 500. Please excuse me if the code is grossly incorrect:

```
if ( !is_admin() ) {
function SearchFilter($query) {
if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
$query->set('post_type', 'page');
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
if ( !is_admin() ) {
function change_wp_search_size($query) {
if ( $query->is_search && !is_admin() )
$query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 10;
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'change_wp_search_size');
```

I'm hoping that I'm close and just need some tweaking for the code

Edit:
So now this is what i have for both functions. I know its my php code which is the problem can you help further please:

```
function SearchFilter($query) {
if ( is_admin () ) {
return $query;
}
else {
($query->is_search) {
$query->set('post_type', 'page');
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');

function change_wp_search_size($query) {
if ( is_admin () ) {
return $query;
}
if ( $query->is_search ) // Make sure it is a search page
$query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 10;

return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'change_wp_search_size');
```

EDIT 2: Pastebin of the entire function.php file http://pastebin.com/tTEnHGp2

Comment: To find out the cause of the error, set `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in your `wp-config.php`. This will show you the error, but only use this if you are using a local server or a development server. See also: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function SearchFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'page');
    }


    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');

function change_wp_search_size($query) {
    if ( $query->is_search && !is_admin() ) {
        $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 10;
    }

    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'change_wp_search_size');
```

This Should do it

Comment: I add this code to the bottom of my functions.php file and it still shows that http 500 error when trying to load the website. I copied and pasted it. I see mine I did not use if on the query search which you did indeed include in your snippet yet it still throws the error. If you'd take a look at it again and make any suggestions I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @d.ariel I've updated the code please check it and add some error catching and checkings where I left comment.

Comment: I copied over your updated code but it still threw the 500 error. Not sure how to do error catching where you have commented the code.

Comment: Since I can't see your full function file I can't say what is wrong but just check though my blue print and modify to what you want.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the entire file. Im using the default 2016 theme for wordpress and I've added the pastebin with the entire functions.php file. http://pastebin.com/tTEnHGp2

Comment: **is_search** is a function and not a variable so I've updated the code to match that requirement **is_search()**

Comment: Yea it is still throwing that error. Here is the functions file with your code inserted at the bottom: http://pastebin.com/S4SawZY3
The code that I have in my question in the first code box works. The problem is it affects the admin functionality in the back end. The code latest code you sent me and which is in the pastebin still causes the 500 error unfortunately. This is basically default WP theme what do you think the issue is?

Comment: @d.ariel I've updated my code I hope this helps ..I love your resilience

Comment: Hey so sorry to leave you hanging. Server meltdown and problem after problem I'm just getting back to fixing this problem now. Yes your updated code does indeed work and I really appreciate the effort you put in here to help me solve this question. Thank you so much and it I think it's working 100% Abolarin stephen

Answer (score 1):

Okay don't wrap your search functions around the *is_admin()* instead put the *is_admin()* inside the function

Like this:

```
Function search(){
    if ( is_admin()){
        //Search query for admin
    }
   else {
       //Search query for users
   }
}
```

That should do it

Comment: I've updated my question. I know there is a syntax error in my php code tried to follow along with your suggestion as best I could. Can you help with correcting the mistakes?